# Regex match to extract data between first ( and last ) incase the data contains brackets?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to extract data from a string of text using Powershell. The data I need is between the first and last bracket. What I have so far appears to work but doesn't work if the data itself contains a close bracket...

```
$MyText = "BT /F3 8.999 Tf 0 0 0 rg 407.446 TL 64.368 772.194 Td (\(TESTJulia\)  Julia's Test Company) Tj T* ET"
[regex]::match($MyText,'(?<=\().+?(?=\))')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
$MyText = "BT /F3 8.999 Tf 0 0 0 rg 407.446 TL 64.368 772.194 Td (\(TESTJulia\)  Julia's Test Company) Tj T* ET"
$match = [regex]::Match($MyText,'\(+?(.*)\)')
Write-Host $match.Captures.groups[1].value
```

> Output:

```
\(TESTJulia\)  Julia's Test Company
```

> Regex explanation (courtesy Regex101.com):

```
\(+? matches the character ( literally (case sensitive)
+? Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
1st Capturing Group (.*)
.* matches any character (except for line terminators)
* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\) matches the character ) literally (case sensitive)
```

Comment: I could work with that... But if we could not include the first and last bracket in the output that would be 100%...
```\(TESTJulia\)  Julia's Test Company```

Comment: Edited with explanation

Answer (score 0):

here's a slightly different way to get there ... [*grin*]

it depends on the `td (` and `) tj` being always there, but it works with your sample data.

```
$InStuff = "BT /F3 8.999 Tf 0 0 0 rg 407.446 TL 64.368 772.194 Td (\(TESTJulia\)  Julia's Test Company) Tj T* ET"

$InStuff -match 'td \((.+)\) tj .+$'

$Matches[1]
```

output ...

```
\(TESTJulia\)  Julia's Test Company
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not remove the lazy quantifier? This will make it greedy so that it grabs as many characters as it can unti it hits the lookahead.

```
PS>$MyText = "BT /F3 8.999 Tf 0 0 0 rg 407.446 TL 64.368 772.194 Td (\(TESTJulia\)  Julia's Test Company) Tj T* ET"
PS>[regex]::match($MyText,'(?<=\().+(?=\))')

Groups   : {0}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 55
Length   : 35
Value    : \(TESTJulia\)  Julia's Test Company
```